# trying to define location on paddle for breakout game to create better ball collision physics

Tags: c#, xna

So I'm trying to figure out how to split the rectangle of my paddle up so i can define different points on the paddle at which the ball can be hit. I want to make it so that if the ball is hit on either the left or right side of the paddle, then the ball direction will change slightly rather than following the exact same path every time.

Here is my paddle class (I started writing the code I would need in the isboxcolliding method but got stuck and confused):

```
class Ball
{
    Texture2D texture;
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 speed;
    Rectangle bounds;
    Rectangle screenBounds;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    bool collisionWithBrick; // Prevents rapid brick removal.



    public Ball(Texture2D texture, Rectangle screenbounds) // Constructor
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.screenBounds = screenbounds;
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get { return texture.Width; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return texture.Height; }
    }

    public Rectangle Bounds
    {
        get
        {
            bounds = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y,
                Width, Height);

            return bounds;
        }
    }

    public void SetStartBallPosition(Rectangle paddle)
    {
        position.X = paddle.X + (paddle.Width - Width) / 2;
        position.Y = paddle.Y = paddle.Y - Height;
        bounds = Bounds;

        if (rnd.Next(0, 2) < 1)
            speed = new Vector2(-200.0f, 200.0f); // Move ball left.
        else
            speed = new Vector2(200.0f, -200.0f); // Move Ball Right.
    }

    internal void Deflection(MultiBallBrick multiBallBrick)
    {
        if (!collisionWithBrick)
        {
            speed.Y *= -1;
            collisionWithBrick = true;
        }
    }

    internal void Deflection(ReinforcedBrick reinforcedBrick)
    {
        if (!collisionWithBrick)
        {
            speed.Y *= -1;
            collisionWithBrick = true;
        }
    }


    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.Silver);
    }


    // Check if our ball collides with the right paddle.
    public void IsBoxColliding(Rectangle paddle)
    {

        if (bounds.Intersects(paddle))
        {
            int center = paddle.Center.X - bounds.Center.X;


            if (center > )
            {
                speed.Y *= -1;



                speed.X = speed.X * 1.5f;
            }
        }

        /*if (paddle.Intersects(bounds)) // Bounds = our ball
        {
            position.Y = paddle.Y - Height;
            speed.Y *= - 1; // Reverse the direction of the ball.
        }*/
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        collisionWithBrick = false;
        position += speed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;


        // Check to see if the ball goes of the screen.
        if (position.X + Width > screenBounds.Width) // Right side
        {
            speed.X *= -1;
            position.X = screenBounds.Width - Width;
        }

        if (position.X < 0) // Left side
        {
            speed.X *= -1;
            position.X = 0;
        }

        if (position.Y < 0) // Top
        {
            speed.Y *= -1;
            position.Y = 0;
        }
    }

    public bool OffBottom()
    {
        if (position.Y > screenBounds.Height)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public void Deflection(Brick brick)
    {
        if (!collisionWithBrick)
        {
            speed.Y *= -1;
            collisionWithBrick = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

any help would be greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to split the collision rectangle up. You can check if the collision is on the left or right side by having the following information.

- The collision point or the centre position of the ball when the collision occurs, lets call it `Vector2 collisionPoint`
- Centre position of the paddle, lets call it `Vector2 paddleCentrePosition`

**This only works if the paddle does not rotate.**

```
Vector2 difference = collisionPoint - paddleCentrePosition;
if(difference.x > 0) {
    /*Right side of the paddle*/
}
else if(difference.x < 0) {
    /*Left side of the paddle*/
}
else{
    /*The exact same position*/
}
```

Comment: thanks, that really helped. Thats what I was thinking of but couldnt get my head round it. One thing though, I have a multiball brick that is on my second level, and for some reason the second ball that spawns, no longer actually interacts with the paddle (nor does it actually interact with the bricks). Any idea why that might have happened? I cant seem to see why because the second ball is set up to collide just like the first(it was colliding before).

Comment: @ESuth No idea. Check if isboxcolliding is being called at all. Do a console print.

Comment: It's definitely being called. I'm basically just spawning another version of my ball class when the multibrick is struck. I dont need to make an entirely new class for the multiball do i?

Comment: @ESuth Multibrick is a brick that spawns a ball? What do you mean another version of ball class? A class that inherets the ball class? If you are overriding the function then you must remember to call the base function